# White blood: cells concentration

Tags: immunology, hematology, lymphatic-system

Anyone knows of a table with average concentration that can be found in  white blood?

Something like:

- Neutrophils - 80%
- Mast cells - ?%
- Dendritic cells - ?%
- B cells - ?%
- Helper T cells - ?%
- Killer T cells - ?%
- Natural killers - ?%
- Others - (whatever is left)
  (the sum should be 100%, of course :))

Also: are helper T cells and killer T cells visually different? I can only find pictures of T cells, but not of each. I am also unable to find pictures of natural killers. - Thank you!

Comment: You mean the concentration of these cells in the blood of "normal" and healthy people?

Comment: [Wikipedia to the rescue!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_blood_cell#Types)

Comment: @Luigi, I have looked up wikipedia. It does not discriminate lymphocytes nor does its source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some figures from *Cellular and Molecular Immunology*, 8th Edition:

[image]

[image]

Hopefully they're helpful in some way.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I needed - btw, do you know if (and why) it is so rare to find photos of helper T cells, killer T cells and B cells? (I can only seem to find pictures of the lymphocyte class ...)

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you mean by photos. Like bright field, scanning electron, transmission electron, etc?

Comment: Yes, pictures of Th, Tc and B cells... I can only find picture of generic lymphocytes. (I am not a biologist!) ps: I know Th,Tc,B,etc are all lymphocytes, but I would like to have pictures of each, if those exist. Do you think they do?